# Android Geofencing: Transition types

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

I am trying to test my android geofencing app. I have entered my current location as the geofence latitude,location and trying to test if the app works. Technically speaking, I am within the geofenced area when I run the app. However, I am not getting any notification when I start the app - the transition type received is -1 when I am within the geofenced area. Is there something else I need to incorporate? Given below is my current code-

```
//once connected to GoogleAPIClient

ArrayList<Geofence> geofences = new ArrayList<Geofence>();
geofences.add(new Geofence.Builder()
        .setRequestId("id")
        .setCircularRegion(
                lat, lon, GEOFENCERADIUS)
        .setTransitionTypes(
                Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL
                        | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
        .setLoiteringDelay(30000) // check every 30 seconds
        .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
        .build());
        System.out.println("GEOFENCE ADDED");
    }

    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(geofences);

    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
            .setFastestInterval(5000L).setInterval(10000L)
            .setSmallestDisplacement(75.0F);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, GeofenceReceiver.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
            locationRequest, pendingIntent);
```

The intent service class is given below:

```
public class GeofenceReceiver extends IntentService {

    public GeofenceReceiver()
    {
        super("GeoFenceReceiver");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        System.out.println("INTENT RECEIVED");

        GeofencingEvent geoEvent=GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

        if (geoEvent.hasError()) {
               //todo error process
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        else {
               int transitionType = geoEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

               System.out.println(transitionType);

               if (transitionType == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                       transitionType == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
                   List<Geofence> triggerList = geoEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

                   for (Geofence geofence : triggerList) {
                       generateNotification(geofence.getRequestId(), "address you defined");
                   }
               }

               if(transitionType==-1)
               {
//                 System.out.println(intent.getAction());
               }
           }
```

When I run the app, I get the message INTENT RECEIVED, however, the transition type is always -1. Is this a problem with the working of the app?

PS : I am sure this has nothing to do with GPS accuracy as I have increased the geofence radius to as large as 2 kms. so I am sure it has something to signify the transition on running the app.

Comment: Are you going out of the fence for testing ?

Comment: No, I am just trying to generate a notification when I am inside the fencing region.

Comment: So you need to go out of given radius to get exit message. You can reduce radius, it should be around 100 m or more.

Comment: Alright, I will give this a try :)

Comment: It does not work! I got my current location using Google API Client and created a geofence at that point with 100 mts radius. Then I walked out of that area..i took a long walk but nothing happened!

Comment: I just need to know what does the transition type -1 represent. Can anybody shed some light on it?

Comment: -1 is for  expiration duration NEVER_EXPIRE. Please you try one thing, When you are adding geofence remove transition type  Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL, use only Entry and Exit.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was probably facing issues with the last location fetched by the Google API Client. Due to poor weather conditions, the mobile network was not able to fetch the exact location and hence no transition type was received. It's all good and working now. Thanks for your effort.